# Code Analysis Warnings in Visual Studio 2010 - CA1007

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I have turned on CA1007 as Error in the ruleset. Then I wrote the below code to violate this rule but it still didn't detect this as either Warning or Error. Not sure where I am making mistake, is it in the code or in the ruleset?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Swap(ref object object1, ref object object2)
    {
        object temp = object1;
        object1 = object2;
        object2 = temp;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string string1 = "Swap";
        string string2 = "It";

        object object1 = (object)string1;
        object object2 = (object)string2;
        Program.Swap(ref object1, ref object2);
        string1 = (string)object1;
        string2 = (string)object2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", string1, string2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The methods is in a private class, which are usually exempt from API rules (since the method isn't a public API). Try making the class public. Also ensure that you are compiling without optimizations a method such as this (especially when private) migth be optimized away by the compiler, causing Code Analysis to be unable to find it.

Comment: From [the documentation for CA1007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182179.aspx): *"An **externally visible** method contains a reference parameter of type System.Object, and the containing assembly targets .NET Framework 2.0. "*

Comment: @jessehouwing: Thank you, that worked! Also, what do you mean by "ensure that you are compiling without optimizations", how would I do that?

Comment: When you compile in "Debug" the optimizations are turned off by default, this prevents the compiler from removing unused code, inline statements and do other stuff that makes your code run faster. Since Code Analysis doesn't actually check the code, but since it checks the compiled `IL`, these types of optimizations can cause certain rules not to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Program` is a private class (it does not have a modifier on it, so it defaults to private), the public static method is not visible from the outside. The [`CA1007`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182179.aspx) is meant to ensure that public API's use a nice signature, but internal, private and otherwise not visible methods are exempt from this rule.